# Upgrade from VS2015 to VS2022: Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'msvcprtd.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, lib

I am trying to upgrade a project from VS2015 to VS2022 and getting the following error:

`Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'msvcprtd.lib'`

When I compile it as 2015 project, it works, but once I switch it to 2022, it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I needed to select the checkmark 'Inherit from parent or project defaults' in library directories

I created a new empty project and compared the library settings with my older project to see what was the difference.